# Scrolling through a JPanel within a JScrollingPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to make a level editor for my platformer game, I want my levels to be 100 by 100 squares.

So far the editor works, but I can't scroll through the JPanel. I've been playing around and I've made a small test class to fiddle with which I'll post. 
If you run it, all it does it show the grid. However if I swap out two variables (I'll comment where) it can show an image and scroll according to the size of that image.

I want that **scrolling ability only for the JPanel**, so that I can scroll through my *100 x 100 square level*.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class ScrollPaneJ extends JFrame {

    // setting the panels
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    // dimensions/ variables of the grid
    int size = 16;
    int startX = 112;
    int startY = 48;
    int width = 30;
    int height = 30;

    // this is the grid
    String[][] grid = new String[width][height];

    // this is from the full editor class
    String currentImage = new String("platform");

    ImageIcon currentBackIcon = new ImageIcon("Resources/backdirttile.jpg");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // adding the scrollpane
                    ScrollPaneJ frame = new ScrollPaneJ();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ScrollPaneJ() {

        setTitle("Scrolling Pane Application");
        setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // defining the top and bottom panels, bottom is what I think I'm
        // drawing on, top is where the scrollpanel goes, I copied this code
        // from the internet and I'm not too sure how it works
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());

        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(bottomPanel);

        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);

        // this is the label I was talking about
        Icon image = new ImageIcon("src/MenuDesign.jpg");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(image);

        // Create a tabbed pane
        // if you set it to say label instead of bottomPanel, you can scroll
        // through the size of the label
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(bottomPanel);
        scrollPane.setBounds(40, 40, 100, 100);
        // set it label here as well.
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(bottomPanel);

        // I was hoping this would force the scrollbar in but it does nothing
        scrollPane
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setBounds(50, 30, 300, 50);
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        topPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        // this sets the grid to empty
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                grid[x][y] = "";

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // this paints the grid
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                g2d.drawRect(x * size + startX, y * size + startY, size, size);

                if (grid[x][y].equals("")) {

                    g2d.drawImage(currentBackIcon.getImage(),
                            x * size + startX, y * size + startY, null);

                }

                g2d.setColor(Color.black);
                g2d.drawRect((x * size) + 1 + startX, (y * size) + 1 + startY,
                        size, size);

            }
        }
    }

    public void drawTile() {
        // this isn't enabled which is why you can't paint the grid, however it
        // would change the tile of the square you're mouse is on, to the
        // current tile, it works and isn't really important for what i need
        // help with
        PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point b = a.getLocation();
        int mouseX = (int) b.getX();
        int mouseY = (int) b.getY();
        int gMX = ((mouseX - 48) / 16) - 4;
        int gMY = ((mouseY - 48) / 16) - 3;

        grid[gMX][gMY] = currentImage;
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worrying: `scrollPane.setBounds(40, 40, 100, 100);`; Wrong: `scrollPane.getViewport().add(bottomPanel);`

Comment: This `JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(null);` is also a very bad idea

Answer (score 3):

1. `scrollPane.getViewport().add(bottomPanel);` should be more like `scrollPane.getViewportView(bottomPanel);`
2. You shouldn't be painting directly to the frame, as child components can be painted without the notification to the parents, meaning that what ever you've painted could be partially wiped out.  Instead, this kind of painting should be done within a custom component which acts as the `JScrollPane`'s, `JViewport`'s view.
3. A `JScrollPane` needs two things, first, the size that the component would like to be (the `preferredSize`) and the size of the viewport view.  If the component doesn't implement the `Scrollable` interface, then the component's `preferredSize` is used to determine that as well.  This is why a `JLabel` will work.

A `JScrollPane` has a `JViewport` as it's primary child component.  The `JViewport` should only have a single component, typically assigned either via `JScrollPane#setViewportView` or `JViewport#setView` methods

[image: JScrollPane]

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Create a custom component that extends `JPanel` and override it's `getPreferredSize` method to return the size of the component you want.  Override it's `paintComponent` method and perform you custom painting their.

Overlaying custom painting ontop of other components is more difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can also add JScrollPane in your panel like this

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
add(new JScrollPane(p));
```

Comment: explanation for zero upvotings, 1. JPanel has (in this case, as is in your code) FlowLayout, 2. this LayoutManager accepts only the PreferredSize from its childs (JScrollPane), JScrollPane and JComboBox don't know returns Dimension properly